# Does local::lib support installing to the project directory?

Tags: perl, dependencies, locallib

With node, when I run `npm install` things get installed into `./node_modules`. Is there any method to make all of my Perl modules install *local* to the project directory? Not to my home directory, or to my system?

Something like `./perl_modules`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `cpanm` with `--local-lib-contained=node_modules`

```
cpanm --local-lib-contained=perl_modules install Mojo
```

Then you can run tell `perl` to use it by setting `-I` like this,

```
perl -I./perl_modules/lib/perl5/ -MMojo -E1
```